# Can I configure IDEA to pick up the style settings for Eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I know that there is an IDEA, eclipse compatibility plugin, will this ensure that my style settings are consistent with the ones included in the project? do I have to take additional action?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ 13+ can import code formatting settings from Eclipse without the compatibility plugin. Export your Eclipse settings and import them to IntelliJ:

`Settings > Code Style > Scheme - Manage > Import > Eclipse XML Profile`

However:

> Keep in mind that code style settings in IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse are fundamentally different and can’t be mapped one to another with complete accuracy, e.g. you can’t tell IntelliJ IDEA to put space
>    after ‘(‘ or not to put it before ‘)’

[Source/More information](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/01/intellij-idea-13-importing-code-formatter-settings-from-eclipse/)

Additionally, IntelliJ 14 will automatically [detect some code styles on the fly](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/intellij-idea-14-will-detect-code-styles-on-the-fly/).